# $.mobile.changePage() after login not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am building a WebWorks app that starts with a login form and if login is successful a second page with the id='map' is supposed to be shown. I tried using $.mobile.changePage to display the page but it only reloads the login page. Why is't it loading the second page?

I stripped out all the login validation code to simplify things so I could figure out why the changePage isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all-1.0.0.css" />
<script src="lib/BlackBerry-JQM-all-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBHGb5Si_2oXtOLCo_IzRIJPtrKkhyFPsU&sensor=false"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>TCOB - Login</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">
    <div class="BB10Container">
      <form method="post">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="user-input" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <label for="basic">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="pass-input" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="page" id="map" >
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>TCoB</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">

  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script> 
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Zur&uuml;ck";
    });

     $('#username').keyup(function(){
         $.get("http://www.hedonsoft.com/tcob/php/check_user.php",{username: $("#username").val()},function(data){
             if(data == true){
                 $('#username').css("background-color","#00FFFF").css("color","#000000");
             }else{
                 $('#username').css("background-color","#000000").css("color","#FFFFFF");
             }
         });
      });

      $('#submit').click(function(){
          $.mobile.changePage("#map");
      });

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}

function getLocation(){

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $.mobile.navigate() seems to be what I'm looking for instead of changePage(); Is this right?

Comment: 1) `mobileinit` should be initiated after loading jQuery and before jQuery Mobile. 2) If you're using latest jQM RC  `$.mobile.toolbar.prototype.options.backBtnText` and change page `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change"," URL/#page");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are both using a custom `click` handler *and* using a `<form>` to submit the form.

The custom click handler will navigate to `#map` and you can actually see that page flash up very briefly, but since your `form` has no `action` attribute, it will redirect to the same page – which is the login page, causing a second navigation and thus resulting in the weird behavior you are experiencing.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j94kC/) without a `form` to see that it works.

However, note that `$.mobile.changePage` is [marked as deprecated](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/10/24/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-rc1-released/) as of 1.4.0 RC1.